Factoring Custom Tensor Products
I have now made a post on the Computer Science stack exchange that talks about the general problems from an algorithmnic perspective here.
I have defined a custom tensor product function TProduct[a,b] -> $a \otimes b$ that behaves as you would expect:
TProduct /: TProduct[a_, b_] TProduct[c_, d_] := TProduct[a c, b d]
TProduct /: TProduct[a_, b_] (f_ + g_) := 
TProduct[a, b] f + TProduct[a, b] g
TProduct[c_ ?NumberQ  f_, g_] := c  TProduct[f, g]
TProduct[f_, c_ ?NumberQ  g_] := c  TProduct[f, g]
TProduct[0, g_] := 0
TProduct[g_, 0] := 0

I wrote a function FactorTProduct[expr_]that factors a given sum of TProduct expressions in a sensible way. Things like:
$$c_1 (a \otimes b) + c_2 (a \otimes d) \to a \otimes (c_1 b+c_2 d)$$.
Hard-coding in (I think) all of the possible cases leads to this:
FactorTProduct[expr_] := 
 expr //. {n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, c_] + 
     m_?NumberQ  TProduct[b_, c_] :> TProduct[n  a + m  b, c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, c_] - m_?NumberQ  TProduct[b_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[n  a - m  b, c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, b_] + m_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[a, n  b + m  c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, b_] - m_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[a, n  b - m  c],(**)
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[-a_, c_] + 
     m_?NumberQ  TProduct[-b_, c_] :> -TProduct[n  a + m  b, c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, -c_] + 
     m_?NumberQ  TProduct[b_, -c_] :> -TProduct[n  a + m  b, c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[-a_, c_] - m_?NumberQ  TProduct[-b_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[n  b - m  a, c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, -c_] - m_?NumberQ  TProduct[b_, -c_] :> 
    TProduct[n  b - m  a, c],(**)
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, -b_] + 
     m_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, -c_] :> -TProduct[a, n  b + m  c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[-a_, b_] + 
     m_?NumberQ  TProduct[-a_, c_] :> -TProduct[a, n  b + m  c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, -b_] - m_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, -c_] :> 
    TProduct[a, n  c - m  b], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[-a_, b_] - m_?NumberQ  TProduct[-a_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[a, n  c - m  b],(**Handling implicit coefficients of 1**)
   TProduct[a_, c_] + TProduct[b_, c_] :> TProduct[a + b, c], 
   TProduct[a_, c_] - TProduct[b_, c_] :> TProduct[a - b, c], 
   TProduct[a_, b_] + TProduct[a_, c_] :> TProduct[a, b + c], 
   TProduct[a_, b_] - TProduct[a_, c_] :> TProduct[a, b - c], 
   TProduct[-a_, c_] + TProduct[-b_, c_] :> -TProduct[a + b, c], 
   TProduct[a_, -c_] + TProduct[b_, -c_] :> -TProduct[a + b, c], 
   TProduct[-a_, c_] - TProduct[-b_, c_] :> TProduct[b - a, c], 
   TProduct[a_, -c_] - TProduct[b_, -c_] :> TProduct[b - a, c], 
   TProduct[a_, -b_] + TProduct[a_, -c_] :> -TProduct[a, b + c], 
   TProduct[-a_, b_] + TProduct[-a_, c_] :> -TProduct[a, b + c], 
   TProduct[a_, -b_] - TProduct[a_, -c_] :> TProduct[a, c - b], 
   TProduct[-a_, b_] - TProduct[-a_, c_] :> TProduct[a, c - b],(**
   Handling cases where one coefficient is 1**)
   TProduct[a_, c_] + n_?NumberQ  TProduct[b_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[a + n  b, c], 
   TProduct[a_, c_] - n_?NumberQ  TProduct[b_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[a - n  b, c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, c_] + TProduct[b_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[n  a + b, c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, c_] - TProduct[b_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[n  a - b, c], 
   TProduct[a_, b_] + n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[a, b + n  c], 
   TProduct[a_, b_] - n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[a, b - n  c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, b_] + TProduct[a_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[a, n  b + c], 
   n_?NumberQ  TProduct[a_, b_] - TProduct[a_, c_] :> 
    TProduct[a, n  b - c]}

This is already deeply inelegant, but it fails in a number of places. In particular:
(1) $(-a -b ) \otimes d + (a + b) \otimes e \not \to (a+b)\otimes (e-d)$
In code: TProduct[-a-b,d] + TProduct[]
(2) $(a+b)\otimes d + 2 (a+b) \otimes e \not \to (a+b) \otimes (d + 2 e)$
In code: TProduct[a + b, d] + 2 TProduct[a + b, e].
I can easily fix (1) by putting something in like:
TProduct[-a_ - b_, c_] :> -TProduct[a + b, c], and I could also do something similar for (2), but I would once again need to consider all of the cases of positive/negative coefficients, etc, etc, and it is getting tediuous. Even with all that, it wouldn't do anything to help with the case of $(a+b+d) \otimes e + 2(a+b +d) \otimes f$ and so on. There must me a more elegant way to do what I am trying to do.
In essence, a well defined version of my goal is I would like to take some long sum of TProduct[] expressions (I already have a good ExpandTProduct[]) function and then factor this long sum into the smallest number of TProducts as possible. An expression with fewer terms is always 'better'. For example I would like:
$$a \otimes d + 7a \otimes e + 2 a \otimes f + b \otimes d + 7b \otimes e + 2 b \otimes f \to (a+b)\otimes (d+7e+2f)$$.

Hi. Before defining FactorTProduct, there is a serious problem. According to your MMA code, both TProduct[a, b] TProduct[c, d] and TProduct[c, d] TProduct[a, b] yield TProduct[a c, b d]. I don't think this is what you want.

Amazingly, this is in fact what I would like. Though it is good to be careful. For me "a" and "b" are things like "Log[z]" and "PolyLog[3,z]" which commute
